# Live Agent liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map Mapping not working

Tags: liveagent, console, chat

We're using Live Agent to Map the Contact on the Basis of Email. Below is the Code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,contactFirstName;LastName,contactLastName;Email,Email;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;Email,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="Contact" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Contact" value="Case,ContactId" />
```

When there's only one Contact Corresponding to an Email, then it's working fine. But when there are more than one Contact's with the same Email, then it's not working. It simply open's up a tab with both the results.

Is there any way I can map it to any one of the Contact in case it encounters more than one contacts with the same Email?

Answer (score 0):

As Salesforce Support was 'NO Help', I resolved this issue myself. What I did, on the Submission of the Form, while Validating I called a Remote Action Method, which performs a SOQL query to look if there are more than one Contact associated with the Email.

This workaround solved my issue.